Upstairs floor sagging 1 1/2". Support post in tight / difficult position
Gist: Would a Ellis Light Support lifting post be sufficient as a permanent fix along with a shimming the original post?
Bought the house four years ago. It has back to back fireplaces(Bedroom & Living room). The CMU bases/supports are in the basement mechanical room. One base is in square, the other is at an angle. There is a space in-between the two where someone placed a 6x6 support post for the four joists seen in the picture.
It is tight in there;  just shy of 3" between the post and the ceiling duct and 6 1/2" from the post to the vertical ducting / furnace. Replacing the post would require removing the furnace, the vertical return, and possibly the part of the ceiling ducting. Hence why I am thinking about the Ellis jack post.


Jacking up a house/floor that has sag, is a very slow process.  Jacking up because of excess weight(fireplaces) might make this a professional job.  Fireplaces(masonry) do not take kindly to movement, like wood does.

@crip659 I appreciate the words of caution. However, the joists are not connected to the fireplace CMU bases. The joists are resting on the 6x6 post standing in-between the CMU. I will only be affecting / jacking the the joists.
